# Loop JSON object and plot to graph

Tags: javascript, json, linechart

Basically I am trying to plot multiple lines on a line chart. The data I retrieved is in JSON format. Here is the code where I tried to plot a line chart:

```
function getLineChartData(busStopNo) {
var Data = JSON.stringify({ busStopNo: busStopNo });
$.ajax({
    url: "index.aspx/getLineChartData",
    type: "POST",
    data: Data,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data.d);
        var parsed = JSON.parse(data.d);
        $.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {
            var time = jsondata.time;
            var t1_10 = jsondata.t1_10;
            var t11_20 = jsondata.t11_20;
            var t21_50 = jsondata.t21_50;
            var t51_above = jsondata.t51_above;               

            var dataOne = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            dataOne.addColumn('number', 'Time');
            dataOne.addColumn('number', 'Total1_10');
            dataOne.addColumn('number', 'Total11_20');
            dataOne.addColumn('number', 'Total21_50');
            dataOne.addColumn('number', 'Total51_above');
            dataOne.addRows([
        [time, t1_10, t11_20, t21_50, t51_above]            
            ]);

            var title = "Age Group Population at Bus Stop " + busStopNo;
            var optionsOne = {
                chartArea: { height: 300, top: 30, left: 50 },
                fontName: 'Arial',
                legend: { alignment: 'center' },
                pieSliceText: 'none',
                tooltip: { trigger: 'none' },
                title: title,
                'width': 330,
                'height': 400,
                sliceVisibilityThreshold: 0
            };
            var chartOne = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('lineChart'));
            chartOne.draw(dataOne, optionsOne);   

        });
    },
    error: function (request, state, errors) {
    }
});
```

I managed to get the data. But somehow, my line chart loop to the end and only plot out the last set of data instead of plotting each set on the line chart. I wonder is there any way to store the data I received in array. And from the array then I loop again to plot out the line chart.

I not sure whether the approach I mentioned above is the best. Thanks in advance.

[image: Database Image]

Comment: To clarify: Adding the data to the table works but plotting the same data fails?

Comment: I am adding data manually to the database. But then my line chart only plot the last time, which is 18 instead of 7-18

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
var chartOne = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('lineChart'));
```

will remove anything in the `lineChart` node and then add a new line chart. That means you just get to see the last one.

If you want several charts, then you need to create individual DOM nodes as parents.

If you want all the data in a single chart, then you need to create the data table *before* of the loop, add each row in the loop and then render the chart once *after* the loop:

```
var dataOne = new google.visualization.DataTable();
$.each(parsed, function (i, jsondata) {
    ...
    dataOne.addRows([
        [time, t1_10, t11_20, t21_50, t51_above]            
    ]);
    ...
} );
var chartOne = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('lineChart'));
var optionsOne = {...};
chartOne.draw(dataOne, optionsOne);
```